# NSIndexPath in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, nsindexpath

I know, hopefully, that class NSIndexPath deals with arrays which has arrays.

I have this code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    let devCourses = [
        ("iOS App Dev with Swift Essential Training","Simon Allardice"),
        ("iOS 8 SDK New Features","Lee Brimelow"),
        ("Data Visualization with D3.js","Ray Villalobos"),
        ("Swift Essential Training","Simon Allardice"),
        ("Up and Running with AngularJS","Ray Villalobos"),
        ("MySQL Essential Training","Bill Weinman"),
        ("Building Adaptive Android Apps with Fragments","David Gassner"),
        ("Advanced Unity 3D Game Programming","Michael House"),
        ("Up and Running with Ubuntu Desktop Linux","Scott Simpson"),
        ("Up and Running with C","Dan Gookin") ]

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return devCourses.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = UITableViewCell()

        let (courseTitle, courseAuthor) = devCourses[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = courseTitle

        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

What I don't understand how NSIndexPath works. I have read documentation but is it still too hard for me to understand at this point of my learning how this works. How can I know NSIndexPath has property of row? Cans somebody explain every part of this line please:

```
let (courseTitle, courseAuthor) = devCourses[indexPath.row]
```

How does NSIndexPath know that courseTitle in this constant refers to index number 0 whitin array index 0 `("iOS App Dev with Swift Essential Training","Simon Allardice")`

Comment: Look up "tuples" in the Swift documentation.

Comment: Xcode has some nice features to help you understand the code you are looking at.  In Xcode, Option-click on `row` in the above statement line, and it will tell you what it is.  In the pop-up, if you click on `NSIndexPath UIKit Additions` next to `Reference`, it will bring up the documentation.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> What I don't understand how NSIndexPath works.

For iOS, you can think of `NSIndexPath` as a read-only structure that contains two `Int` properties `section` and `row` if you're working with `UITableView`s or `section` and `item` if you're working with `UICollectionView`s.

You create them with the `NSIndexPath:forRow:inSection:` factory method:

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)
```

and read them by accessing their properties:

```
print("row is \(indexPath.row)")
```

> How can I know NSIndexPath has property of row?

Xcode has some nice features to help you understand the code you are looking at. In Xcode, <kbd>Option</kbd>-click on `row` in the above statement line, and it will tell you what it is. In the pop-up, if you click on *NSIndexPath UIKit Additions* next to *Reference*, it will bring up the documentation.

> Can somebody explain every part of this line please:

```
let (courseTitle, courseAuthor) = devCourses[indexPath.row]
```

`devCourses` is an array of tuples containing two values of type `String`.  You can see this by <kbd>option</kbd>-clicking on `devCourses` and it shows `[(String, String)]`.  Had it been an array of array of `String` it would have said `[[String]]` or `[Array<String>]` (which is two ways of saying the same thing).

`indexPath.row` is just an `Int` indicating the selected row of the `tableView`.

`devCourses[indexPath.row]` then is the tuple at that index.  For example, if the `row` were `0`, then the tuple would be `("iOS App Dev with Swift Essential Training","Simon Allardice")`.

Finally, you can initialize two variables simultaneously by declaring them as a tuple and initializing them with a tuple.  For example:

```
let (a, b) = (3, 4)
```

creates two `Int` constants `a` and `b` and assigns `3` to `a` and `4` to `b`.

So this statement is retrieving the tuple from the array indicated by the integer `indexPath.row` and creating two variables, assigning the first variable `courseTitle` the value of the first value in the tuple and assigning the second variable `courseAuthor` the value of the second value in the tuple.

---

**Update for Swift 3**

`NSIndexPath` still exists in *Foundation*, but when working with indexPaths in **Swift 3**, a new type `IndexPath` is now used.  This type is a *structure*.

You can still create an `NSIndexPath` in Swift 3, with the following updated syntax, but you can't change the properties:

```
var ip = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

ip.row = 5    // Cannot assign to property: 'row' is a get-only property
```

but you should use the new `IndexPath` structure instead.

`IndexPath` is created with a similar syntax:

```
var ip2 = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

ip2.row = 5   // this works
```

You can convert between `IndexPath` and `NSIndexPath` by casting with `as`:

```
let ip = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
let ip2 = ip as IndexPath     // convert to IndexPath
let ip3 = ip2 as NSIndexPath  // convert back to NSIndexPath
```

All of the *Cocoa* and *Cocoa Touch* API's that use indexPaths have been converted to use `IndexPath` in Swift.

Comment: swift3 : `let indexPath = IndexPath(row: someRow, section: someSection)`

Comment: Thanks @AmrLotfy, I have updated the answer with Swift 3 information.

Answer (score 6):

Slightly off topic, but I'd like to encourage everybody to use custom classes for the model rather than "primitive" types. There's a little effort but big benefit.

Simple class with two properties and a description (the description variable is helpful while debugging)

```
class DevCourse : Printable {

  var author : String
  var title : String

  init(author : String, title : String) {
    self.author = author
    self.title = title
  }

  var description : String { return "DevCourse \(title) by \(author)"}
}
```

The `devCourses` array can be easily mapped to create the `DevCourse` instances with one line

```
  let rawDevCourses = [
    ("iOS App Dev with Swift Essential Training","Simon Allardice"),
    ("iOS 8 SDK New Features","Lee Brimelow"),
    ("Data Visualization with D3.js","Ray Villalobos"),
    ("Swift Essential Training","Simon Allardice"),
    ("Up and Running with AngularJS","Ray Villalobos"),
    ("MySQL Essential Training","Bill Weinman"),
    ("Building Adaptive Android Apps with Fragments","David Gassner"),
    ("Advanced Unity 3D Game Programming","Michael House"),
    ("Up and Running with Ubuntu Desktop Linux","Scott Simpson"),
    ("Up and Running with C","Dan Gookin") ]

let devCourses = rawDevCourses.map { DevCourse(author: $0.1, title: $0.0) }
```

the lines to apply the properties look much clearer

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    let course = devCourses[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = course.title

    return cell
}
```